# Strange Problem with UIDatePicker in ActionSheet - Below that Selection indicator I can't select anything, It's become like disabled

Tags: iphone, uidatepicker

I am implementing datepicker with Action Sheet with the following code :

-(void)popupActionSheetWithDatePicker
{

```
UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Done",nil];

UIDatePicker *picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
self.datePicker = picker;
[self.datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
[sheet addSubview:self.datePicker];
[sheet showInView:self.view];

[sheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0, 320,500)];

CGRect pickerRect = self.datePicker.bounds;
pickerRect.origin.y = -80;
self.datePicker.bounds = pickerRect;

[sheet bringSubviewToFront:self.datePicker];

[picker release];
[sheet release];   }
```

Now, The Picker pops up & working perfactly Except below the Selection Indicator.

I mean On & Above the Selection indicator I am able to choose date, month & year, but Below that Selection indicator I can't select anything, It's become like disabled.

Can't find the reason or solution.

If Possible Please send any working Datepicker with UIActionsheet code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have had a very similar issue with parts of a view not working when used with a UIActionSheet. My problem was that the bounds of the UIActionSheet were larger than the view I had added it to.

My solutions was to change where i inserted the sheet

```
[sheet showInView:self.view];
```

You may need to add it higher up for example

```
[sheet showInView:self.view.superview];
```

Hope this at least sets you on the right track

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also , i supose you have an UIToolbar behind the picker. Just do

`[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES];`

while in picker , then

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];
```

hope this help